# Drupal 7 - Like Button counter not changing

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7

I have a code, css, js and everything, when I click the button, it changes it's state but the counter next to it stays the same. Counter only changes when I refresh the page, how can this be fixed?

Here is the code.

```
/**
* Implements hook_menu().
*/
function likepost_menu() {
    $items['likepost/like/%'] = array(
        'title' => 'Like',
        'page callback' => 'likepost_like',
        'page arguments' => array(2),
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'type' => MENU_SUGGESTED_ITEM,
    );
    return $items;
}


function likepost_like($nodeid) {
    $nodeid = (int)$nodeid;
    global $user;

    $like = likepost_get_like($nodeid, $user->uid);

    if ($like !== 0) {
        db_delete('likepost_table_for_likes')
        ->condition('userid', $user->uid)
        ->condition('nodeid', $nodeid)
        ->execute();
        //Update the like value , which will be sent as response
        $like = 0;
    } else {
        db_insert('likepost_table_for_likes')
        ->fields(array(
        'userid' => $user->uid,
        'nodeid' => $nodeid
        ))
        ->execute();
        //Update the like value , which will be sent as response
        $like = 1;
    }

    $total_count = likepost_get_total_like($nodeid);
    drupal_json_output(array(
        'like_status' => $like,
        'total_count' => $total_count
        )
    );

}

/**
* Return the total like count for a node.
*/
function likepost_get_total_like($nid) {
    $total_count = db_query('SELECT count(*) from {likepost_table_for_likes} where nodeid = :nodeid',
    array(':nodeid' => $nid))->fetchField();
    return (int)$total_count;
}

/**
* Return whether the current user has liked the node.
*/
function likepost_get_like($nodeid, $userid) {
    $like = db_query('SELECT count(*) FROM {likepost_table_for_likes} WHERE
    nodeid = :nodeid AND userid = :userid', array(':nodeid' => $nodeid, ':userid' => $userid))->fetchField();
    return (int)$like;
}

/**
 * Implementation of hook_node_view
 */
function likepost_node_view($node, $view_mode) {
    if ($view_mode == 'full'){
        $node->content['likepost_display'] =  array('#markup' => display_like_post_details($node->nid),'#weight' => 100);

        $node->content['#attached']['js'][] = array('data' => drupal_get_path('module', 'likepost') .'/likepost.js');
        $node->content['#attached']['css'][] = array('data' => drupal_get_path('module', 'likepost') .'/likepost.css');
    } 

}

/**
* Displays the Like post details.
*/
function display_like_post_details($nid) {

    global $user;
    $totalLike =  likepost_get_total_like($nid);
    $hasCurrentUserLiked = likepost_get_like($nid , $user->uid);

    return theme('like_post',array('nid' =>$nid, 'totalLike' =>$totalLike, 'hasCurrentUserLiked' => $hasCurrentUserLiked));

}
/**
* Implements hook_theme().
*/
function likepost_theme() {
    $themes = array (
        'like_post' => array(
            'arguments' => array('nid','totalLike','hasCurrentUserLiked'),
        ),
    );
    return $themes;
}

function theme_like_post($arguments) {
    $nid = $arguments['nid'];
    $totalLike = $arguments['totalLike'];
    $hasCurrentUserLiked = $arguments['hasCurrentUserLiked'];
    global $base_url;
    $output = '<div class=”likepost”>';
    $output .= 'Total number of likes on the post are ';
    $output .= '
'.$totalLike.'
';

    if($hasCurrentUserLiked == 0) {
        $linkText = 'Like';
    } else {
        $linkText = 'Delete Like';
    }

    $output .= l($linkText, $base_url.'/likepost/like/'.$nid, array('attributes' => array('class' => 'like-link')));

    $output .= '</div>'; 
    return $output;

}
```

Also the css is not working when I enable the module. I am new in Drupal, hope you can help me. Here is the js file

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery('a.like-link').click(function () {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST', 
            url: this.href,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                if(data.like_status == 0) {
                    jQuery('a.like-link').html('Like');
                }
                else {
                    jQuery('a.like-link').html('Delete Like');
                }

                jQuery('.total_count').html(data.total_count);
            },
            data: 'js=1' 
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```